# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cannot add session into the cache

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a non-sharded mongo cluster with `maxIncomingConnections: 500`. There were no application code changes but recently app is facing the below error. What is the reason for this error and how to resolve the issue.

```
ERROR:
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: cannot add session into the cache

db.serverStatus().logicalSessionRecordCache
{
"activeSessionsCount" : 174,
"sessionsCollectionJobCount" : 595,
"lastSessionsCollectionJobDurationMillis" : 108,
"lastSessionsCollectionJobTimestamp" : ISODate("2023-08-18T17:09:40.113Z"),
"lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesRefreshed" : 0,
"lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesEnded" : 381,
"lastSessionsCollectionJobCursorsClosed" : 0,
"transactionReaperJobCount" : 595,
"lastTransactionReaperJobDurationMillis" : 0,
"lastTransactionReaperJobTimestamp" : ISODate("2023-08-18T17:09:40.113Z"),
"lastTransactionReaperJobEntriesCleanedUp" : 0
 }
 db.serverStatus().connections;
 {
"current" : 28,
"available" : 472,
"totalCreated" : 315382,
"active" : 2
 }
```

When `maxIncomingConnections` was increased to 1000, the error no longer occurred. But what are the other options I can work on to resolve this situation.

Comment: Does `sharding` appear in any of the server configuration files?

Comment: Sharding is commented in the configuration files. Meaning sharding is not configured.